# Have access to a common class in a PHP MVC framework

Tags: php, class, model-view-controller, dependency-injection

I have read a lot of SO topics about this already, but still haven't found (or have been able to create) a proper answer.

I am working on a small MVC framework and I want some global class/object that I can call from my controllers (but maybe models too).

There are a couple of routes I can take:

1. Global variable
2. Static class/Registry
3. Dependency injection

The internet seems to agree that the DI is the best route to take. I think I have grasped the idea, but am not comfortable yet. So I want to throw in some background information; I will probably be the only one working on the project, it is a small project, all my controllers extend the main Controller (so I could just load one library like class there).

As a concrete example, I want to have an array of categories. So I started out with putting that array in the CategoryController. But now I noticed I kinda want to use that array in my frontview and in ProductController as well. Obviously I don't want to load all of CategoryController into ProductController.
You could also say I could put that array in some kind of configuration or settings file, because of the simpleness of this example, but that's why it's an example. I will probably expand on it with more functionality.

So to summarize: In PHP (specifically inside a MVC model) how can you give your classes (mainly Controllers) access to some kind of common class or other sharable functionality.

Comment: Why does you controller do anything besides handling the request and returning a response?

Comment: Probably because it isn't perfect and I made it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your controllers are created by "something" (usually a front controller). So when the controller is created, you could inject a dependency injection container.

And in your configuration/bootstrap (before the controller is created), you should add you categories to the container.

That way you can access the categories from every controller.

Please note that this is a simple example that doesn't totally fit the spirit of dependency injection. The best solution would be to inject directly the categories (instead of injecting the container). But that can become a lot of work if you generalize that pattern (lots of dependencies to handle in your front controller).

A solution would be to use a dependency injection framework that could do that for you.

For example I work on a DI container that lets you inject stuff with annotations ([PHP-DI](http://mnapoli.github.com/PHP-DI/)), but there are several other libraries for DI so you have a choice.

Comment: But it's like a blackbox. Because of the MVC, the controllers get called auto-magically. So then all my controllers would get the same DI container. Or should I specify in a config file which controller gets what?

Comment: It's not a problem if they get all the same container (you pick which data you want in it). Like I said, this is a reduced version of correct dependency injection. With DI, you would not inject the container but the dependency (for example, you would inject you category array to the controllers that need it).

Comment: So all in all, either you want to do "correct" DI, then you have to specify which controller gets what with config files (for example), and develop the stuff to make it work (or use a DI library). Or either you don't really care (you want the stuff to work) and you inject the container and you're done! It really depends if the project is serious, don't overcomplicate if a quick and dirty solution works for you.

Answer (score -1):

My 2 cents:

In a small self-made mini-framework I have done some time ago, I have created a global singleton class named Application, and anything/everything which should be accessible from anywhere/everywhere was a property or method of this class.

In my case, there was a `$db` property for database access, a `$user` property to access the user data and methods, an `$input` property for a "powered" `$_REQUEST` access, and so on.

Of course, you have many other options, suitable for different scenarios. This approach simply worked fine for me on that occasion.

Now, if you want to access a controller from another controller, this really sounds strange. This "thing" that you want to access should be a model class, a library class, or anything else, but it should not be "locked" inside a controller class. Indeed, the controller should be "as thin as possible", and focus on calling the appropriated methods from other classes, based on the user input (request) and then calling some output method to generate and send the answer (response).

Finally, although I've read some criticism and complaints about it (as well as praises too), I do make use of `static` methods a lot, mainly for classes which are more "helpers" than anything else.

Comment: Sounds like a very hard to maintain `global` fest.

Comment: Yeah, I shouldn't have called it that. I am looking more for a library-like entity yes.

Comment: Hard to maintain? ... not really, nothing complex. The Application class was very thin. The "db", "user", "input", "cache" and other classes, for usage in any App, were nice and more robust.

Comment: @PeeHaa How is a single global (one singleton) a fest?

Comment: @lafor "I do make use of static methods a lot" <-- have fun testing flaky results

Comment: @PeeHaa Can't see anything wrong with static helper methods like, say, `HTML::link()`, `HTML::img()` etc. The very nature of helpers is they rarely maintain any state.

Comment: @PeeHaa You are wrong. Please read: http://lithify.me/docs/manual/appendices - the answer to "You guys use statics all over the place. Aren't those really hard to test?"

Comment: @lafor They introduce hidden dependencies (i.e. I do not know there is some dependency by reading the method / class signature). It introduces tight coupling (i.e. you cannot swap that class for another class without changing the class itself).

Comment: @PeeHaa No. It depends on how and where you are using them. It's not an absolute truth you can copy & paste just anywhere "static" appears! Anyway... why don't you write a constructive answer instead of merely making poor criticism of other's answers?

Comment: http://nikic.github.com/2011/12/27/Dont-be-STUPID-GRASP-SOLID.html or http://www.g-truc.net/post-0182.html You don't have to take my word.

Comment: Interesting so far. While I'm only in the "S", I repeat: it DEPENDS on how/where you use. My ultra-thin APP class has a `$db` property. The Database class itself can be instantiated as many times wanted... let's see the "T" now...

Comment: No it does not depend. Everytime you use some static member somewhere you are tightly coupling that class.

Comment: @PeeHaa If a class or method has dependencies, I wouldn't make it static in the first place. What I'm trying to say is I can't see anything wrong with a "library" of dependency-free helper "functions" organized as static methods for ease of access.

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/W8TMrD. I.e. your are violating [OCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle).

Comment: @PeeHaa How exactly `Bar` constructor requiring an instance of `Foo` and `Bar::baz()` returning `$fooinstance->whatNow()` is supposed to make any difference here?

Comment: Because you can easily swap the `Foo` class for another class (i.e. loose coupling).

Comment: @PeeHaa For another class implementing `whatNow()`. Still can't see a difference.